# how to get squared corners with frameless windows in electronjs on macOS?

Tags: javascript, window, electron

I am creating an electron app and i've noticed that frameless windows have rounded corners. In fact most apps have rounded corners on macOS. The problem is i totally want to have an app with squared corners like on Windows 10.

I've tried to set `radii: [0,0,0,0]` but it does not work.

Here's the code i'm using for creating my window:

```
win = createWindow(
    { 
      width,
      height,
      frame: false,
      transparent: true,
      radii: [0,0,0,0]
    }, 
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'renderer/index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
    }),
    mainClose
  )
```

Anyone with any suggestion or code solution even ?

I've also noticed that when windows are transparent on macOS they have a top whitish border. Any guess on how i can solve this ?

Cheers,
MK

Comment: You could try creating a transparent/frameless window and then have the body be square.  If you do that you would have to recreate the close, minimize, and maximize buttons as well as a toolbar in the app.

Comment: I don't think they've implemented this yet but you could try looking at this thread for workarounds: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/414

Comment: `radii` does not even exist as a property ???